# Program won't enter for loop

Tags: c, scanf

Hello I am pretty new to programming.

I know that there is a lot of already asked questions on this topic, but i read them all and  still can't figure where is the problem. The assignment is to write programm that will take 4-digit number and multiply those for digits( exp. 1576; 1*5*6*7). The programm runs bat ok untill for loop and then just stop(doesn't even say that there is some error). Thanks in advance for your help

```
#include< stdio.h >
#include <math.h>
main()
{
 int n,i,b=4,proizvod=1 ; 
 printf("Unesite prirodan cetvorocifreni broj:");
 scanf_s("%d ", &n);
 for (i = 0; i < b; b--) {
     proizvod = proizvod * n % 10;
     n = n / 10;
 }
  printf("Prozivod cifara je: %d", proizvod);
}
```

Comment: No, the program runs until it gets to `scanf`, and then it never returns because it's still waiting for you to type more input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its wait for extra input because of `space` given after `%d` inside `scanf_s()`.
remove the space after `%d`.

```
scanf_s("%d ", &n); // space is causing scanf_s() to wait for another input
```

coming to your logic , no need to take `b=4`, your input can of any digit, so rotate loop until `n` not becomes `zero` as below.

```
       while(n!=0){ /* rotate loop until n not becomes zero */
                proizvod = proizvod * (n % 10);
                n = n / 10;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic is valid only for four digit number. In case if you want to code it for any number then use the logic `while(n!=0)`. And the reason for no output is already explained by others. Remove the Space after %d .